# Can't add item to array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a new node to my array which I thought was a new empty array already created when I had called createList() so I must be doing something wrong because I get an error that list.nodes is undefined.

```
var head = createNode(null);

var list = createList();
list.nodes.push(head); // error is here, undefined array

function List(){

  this.nodes = [];
  this.addNodeToList = addNodeToList;

  function addNodeToList(data){

    var currentNode = head;
    var newNode = createNode(data);

    while(currentNode.getNextNode() != null){
      currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
    }

    currentNode.nextNode = newNode;

    return;
  }
}


function createNode(data){
    return new Node(data);
}

function createList(){
  return new List();
}

function Node(data){
  this.data = data;
  this.nextNode = null;
}

function createList(){
  return new Node(null);
}
```

Comment: where are you executing this script...

Comment: You have two `createList` functions in your code.

Comment: may be just `list.push(head);` as `List`(don't know what kind of object it is) don't have an array named `nodes` as its property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined creatList function twice.
The later definition does not return nodes array:

```
 function createList(){
  return new Node(null);
}
```

Delete it and you should be fine

EDIT:
Consider the following:

```
var a = 5;
var a = 6;
//OR
var f = function (){ alert(1)}
var f = function (){ alert(2)}
```

Since JS does not support function overload, declaring a function twice  has the same effect as the assignment above - the later hides the erlier

Comment: You should explain why JS executes the second `createList` instead of the first one.

Comment: omg, how the f did I miss that.  I think it's because it's 1am.

Comment: Added a shot explanation